# Found highest and lowest values in a list, now need to find their position (java)

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, java.util.scanner

UPDATE: Figured it out, code has been fixed below. Added a while loop to confirm values 0 or above are entered too.

So I'm doing an assignment where the user enters 8 scores and you must find the highest and lowest scores and their position in the order they were given. I have been able to find the highest and lowest scores but I can't figure out how to find their position. Please help me. Here is my code so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HighestLowestPoints {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int largest = -1;
    int smallest = 0;
    int highGame = 1;
    int lowGame = 1;

    for(int games = 1; games <= 8; games++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the Texans' score in game " + games);
        int points = keyboard.nextInt();
        while(points < 0) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a value 0 or above");
            points = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
        if(games == 1) {
            smallest = points;
        }
        if(points > largest) {
            largest = points;
            highGame = games;
        }
        if(points < smallest) {
            smallest = points;
            lowGame = games;
        }
        if(games == 8){
            System.out.println(largest + " in game " + highGame + "\n" 
                              + smallest + " in game " + lowGame);
        }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `position`? Is it when they were entered (i.e., `largest` was the 5th number entered)?

Comment: Cool, glad you got it working. In the future, please include specific details like that so that clarifying questions are unnecessary. Also, instead of editing your original question with the corrected code, post an answer below if you feel so inclined. The problem with correcting your original code is that now all the answers people have written have basically been invalidated. Just FYI for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your almost there. You need to add to variables to save the hightGame and lowestGame and just assign them when you set the highest and the lowest score respectively.

Ex:

```
    if(points < smallest) {
        smallest = points;
        lowestGame = games;
    }
```

Comment: Wow very fast responses! Thanks guys, I feel like such an idiot. I immediately figured it out after I posted the question and looked over the code again. Then I came back here and there's tons of responses saying to just make two more variables. haha anyway thanks again guys. great community!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the game counter variable in your for loop it contains your position :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add another 2 variables, maxIndex and minIndex and when setting smallest or largest, set the appropriate variable as well with "games" variable (contains the position).

Answer (score 0):

create two new variables:

int highPos = -1;
   int lowPos = -1;

Every time you assign smallest, assign games to lowPos
Every time you assign highest, assign games to highPos.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
int lPos = 0, sPos = 0;
```

before your `for` loop.

add this `lPos = games` to your if-block where your find largest number and `sPos = games` to if-block with lowest.

Answer (score 0):

Also why do you assign the lowest to the first game, but not the highest?

```
if(games == 1) {
    smallest = points;
}
```

Comment: Because all games will be higher than 0 which is the original value for highest. I assigned smallest to the first game because the rest of the games need something to compare to and I didn't want to set the original value of lowest to be a million or something.

Answer (score 0):

Just for your information. You could also avoid all these different if's and making the code more readable if you would you would store all your games in an `ArrayList`. And then use the method `Collections.max` to get the maximum game and `Collections.min` to get your minimum game. Then with the method `list.indexOf`you could find the position where the value is added to the list.

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int games = 1; games <= 8; games++) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the Texans' score in game " + games);
    int points = keyboard.nextInt();
    while(points < 0) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a value 0 or above");
    points = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    numbers.add(points);
}
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
output.append("Maximum points: " + Collections.max(numbers));
output.append(" in game: " + (numbers.indexOf(Collections.max(numbers)) + 1));
output.append(" minimum points: " + Collections.min(numbers));
output.append(" in game: " + (numbers.indexOf(Collections.min(numbers)) + 1));
System.out.println(output.toString());
```